# Remove preinstalled GNOME applications

Tags: debian, gnome

I just installed Debian "Bullseye" with GNOME, but it comes with a lot of unwanted applications which I want to remove. I went ahead and searched for the corresponding package names. I also checked if a given application can be removed in the software center.

| Application | Package | Removing Method |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2048 | gnome-2048 | Software Center |
| Advanced Network Configuration | network-manager-gnome | Terminal |
| AisleRiot Solitaire | aisleriot | Software Center |
| Archive Manager | file-roller | Terminal |
| Calculator | gnome-calculator | Terminal |
| Calender | gnome-calendar | Software Center |
| Characters | gnome-characters | Terminal |
| Cheese | cheese | Software Center |
| Chess | gnome-chess | Software Center |
| Clocks | gnome-clocks | Software Center |
| Color Profile Viewer | gnome-color-manager | Software Center |
| Contacts | gnome-contacts | Software Center |
| Disk Usage Analyzer | baobab | Terminal |
| Disks | gnome-disk-utility | Software Center |
| Document Scanner | simple-scan | Software Center |
| Document Viewer | evince | Terminal |
| Documents | gnome-documents | Software Center |
| Evolution | evolution | Software Center |
| Extensions | gnome-shell-extension-prefs | Software |
| Files | nautilus | Software Center |
| Firefox ESR | firefox-esr | Terminal |
| Five or More | five-or-more | Software Center |
| Fonts | gnome-font-viewer | Terminal |
| Four-in-a-row | four-in-a-row | Software Center |
| Help | yelp | Terminal |
| Hitori | hitori | Software Center |
| Image Viewer | eog | Terminal |
| Input Method | im-config | Software Center |
| Klotski | gnome-klotski | Software Center |
| LibreOffice | libreoffice-common | Terminal |
| LibreOffice Calc | libreoffice-calc | Software Center |
| LibreOffice Draw | libreoffice-draw | Software Center |
| LibreOffice Impress | libreoffice-impress | Software Center |
| LibreOffice Writer | libreoffice-writer | Software Center |
| Lights Off | lightsoff | Software Center |
| Logs | gnome-logs | Software Center |
| Mahjongg | gnome-mahjongg | Software Center |
| Maps | gnome-maps | Software Center |
| Mines | gnome-mines | Software Center |
| Music | gnome-music | Software Center |
| Nibbles | gnome-nibbles | Software Center |
| Parental Controls | malcontent | Software Center |
| Passwords and Keys | seahorse | Software Center |
| Quadrapassel | quadrapassel | Software Center |
| Reversi | iagno | Software Center |
| Rhythmbox | rhythmbox | Software Center |
| Robots | gnome-robots | Software Center |
| Screenshot | gnome-screenshot | Terminal |
| Shotwell | shotwell | Software Center |
| Software & Updates | software-properties-gtk | Software Center |
| Software | gnome-software | Terminal |
| Sound Recorder | gnome-sound-recorder | Software Center |
| Sudoku | gnome-sudoku | Software Center |
| Swell Foop | swell-foop | Software Center |
| Synaptic Package Manager | synaptic | Software Center |
| System Monitor | gnome-system-monitor | Terminal |
| Tali | tali | Software Center |
| Taquin | gnome-taquin | Software Center |
| Terminal | gnome-terminal | Terminal |
| Tetravex | gnome-tetravex | Software Center |
| Text Editor | gedit | Terminal |
| To Do | gnome-todo | Software Center |
| Transmission | transmission-gtk | Software Center |
| Tweaks | gnome-tweaks | Software Center |
| Videos | totem | Terminal |
| Weather | gnome-weather | Software Center |

The following command purges every application that could be removed in the software center:

```
apt purge aisleriot cheese evolution five-or-more four-in-a-row gnome-2048 gnome-calendar gnome-chess gnome-clocks gnome-color-manager gnome-contacts gnome-disk-utility gnome-documents gnome-klotski gnome-logs gnome-mahjongg gnome-maps gnome-mines gnome-music gnome-nibbles gnome-robots gnome-sound-recorder gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-sudoku gnome-taquin gnome-tetravex gnome-todo gnome-tweaks gnome-weather hitori iagno im-config libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw libreoffice-impress libreoffice-writer lightsoff malcontent nautilus quadrapassel rhythmbox seahorse shotwell simple-scan software-properties-gtk swell-foop synaptic tali transmission-gtk
```

This additional command purges the applications that can only be removed through the terminal. (I didn't include `network-manager-gnome` and `gnome-terminal` since removing these will cause a lot of annoyance.)

```
apt purge baobab eog evince file-roller firefox-esr gedit gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-font-viewer gnome-screenshot gnome-software gnome-system-monitor libreoffice-common totem yelp
```

Finally, the following command combines the two above:

```
apt purge aisleriot baobab cheese eog evince evolution file-roller firefox-esr five-or-more four-in-a-row gedit gnome-2048 gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-characters gnome-chess gnome-clocks gnome-color-manager gnome-contacts gnome-disk-utility gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-klotski gnome-logs gnome-mahjongg gnome-maps gnome-mines gnome-music gnome-nibbles gnome-robots gnome-screenshot gnome-software gnome-sound-recorder gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-sudoku gnome-system-monitor gnome-taquin gnome-tetravex gnome-todo gnome-tweaks gnome-weather hitori iagno im-config libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-draw libreoffice-impress libreoffice-writer lightsoff malcontent nautilus quadrapassel rhythmbox seahorse shotwell simple-scan software-properties-gtk swell-foop synaptic tali totem transmission-gtk yelp
```

Is there a better way to achieve a minimal install than running the commands above?

Comment: `apt install gnome-session gnome-shell gnome-backgrounds gnome-applets gnome-control-center gnome-terminal` on a clean minimal GUI-less debian image. You might need to add `--no-install-recommends`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed Debian, you probably installed the "Gnome" desktop (bringing in the `gnome` package).

`gnome` itself is a metapackage, which means it doesn't instally anything useful itself,  it simply brings in dependencies.  The description says:

> This is the GNOME Desktop environment, an intuitive and attractive
> desktop, with extra components.
> This metapackage depends on the standard distribution of the GNOME
> desktop environment, plus a complete range of plugins and other
> applications integrating with GNOME and Debian, providing the best
> possible environment to date.

Therefore the `gnome` metapackage is not aimed at providing a minimal install, but a full install, with an office suite, photo viewers, games, etc.

@mashuptwice has a good comment that will work for an installation "from-scratch", but it's possible to get into that same state without re-installing your machine.

I had experienced previously that uninstalling `evolution` will uninstall the packages that depend on it (i.e. `gnome`).  Doing that will mark other dependencies (e.g. `gnome-core`) for autoremoval unless they are explicitly marked as manually installed.

If you want the Gnome desktop environment without the "extra components", take a look at the `Depends:`, `Recommends:` and `Suggests:` section and choose which parts you want to manually install:

```
$ apt show gnome
Package: gnome
Section: metapackages
...
Depends: 
 gnome-core, 
 desktop-base, 
 network-manager-gnome,
 libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager,
 cheese,
 file-roller,
 gnome-calendar,
 gnome-clocks,
 gnome-color-manager,
 gnome-documents,
 gnome-maps,
 gnome-music,
 shotwell | gnome-photos,
 gnome-screenshot,
 gnome-todo,
 gnome-weather,
 orca,
 rygel-playbin,
 rygel-tracker,
 simple-scan,
 avahi-daemon,
 evolution,
 gnome-sound-recorder,
 gnome-tweaks,
 libreoffice-gnome,
 libreoffice-writer,
 libreoffice-calc,
 libreoffice-impress,
 libgsf-bin,
 rhythmbox,
 seahorse,
 xdg-user-dirs-gtk,
 cups-pk-helper,
 evolution-plugins,
 gedit-plugins,
 gstreamer1.0-libav,
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly,
 rhythmbox-plugins,
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder,
 totem-plugins
Recommends: 
 nautilus-extension-brasero,
 gnome-remote-desktop,
 gnome-games,
 transmission-gtk
Suggests:
 alacarte,
 empathy,
 goobox | sound-juicer,
 polari,
 vinagre,
 webext-ublock-origin,
 firefox-esr-l10n-all | firefox-l10n-all
```

Steps:

1. Choose the components you want,
2. Either `sudo apt install <pkg>...` or `sudo apt-mark manual <pkg>...` each of these components.  This will mark them as "manually installed".
3. `sudo apt purge gnome` to remove the `gnome` metapackage.
4. `sudo apt autoremove` to remove all of `gnome`'s dependencies which were not manually installed.

---

You'll note that things like `gnome-chess` are not listed in the dependencies here. They are further down the tree (brought in by `gnome-games`).  You probably don't want to deal with dependencies of dependencies, that's frustrating.  Just deal with the metapackage and everything else will be taken care of.